# How did the scientists reach the cross product?

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to know the origin of the cross product And his relationship with' Groupe compact'

Comment: The cross product makes the vector space $\Bbb{R}^3$ into a $3$-dimensional Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}_3(\Bbb{R})$. It is the Lie algebra of the *compact* Lie group $SO_3(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos The linked question doesn't show the relationship with "compact group".

Comment: The OP should post a new question, only with the second part. The first part really is a duplicate.